# How to make the ID column into a variable?

Tags: r, economics

```
library("pdfetch")
data <- pdfetch_FRED(c("GFDEBTN", "GDPC1"))
```

I want the ID, which shows dates, to be created as a variable. Does anyone have any idea on what's the best way to do this?

Comment: Do you need `rownames_to_column`?

Comment: I'm trying to use the rowid_to_column function, but now getting a is.data.frame(df) is not TRUE error.

Comment: I found a solution that worked by browsing other questions. I added the following line of code: dplyr::as_tibble(data, rownames = "Date")